# get "required' div elements via DOM in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 div in a wizard. On clicking next in wizard i want to validate if required elements are filled.

If i write `y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input")`, all the elements for that div comes. but on applying querySelectorAll `y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input").querySelectorAll("[required]");` the buttons stop to work.

```
x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");

y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input").querySelectorAll("[required]");
```

Comment: querySelector* and the other methods searches decendents not elements in the returned NodeList/HTMLCollection from calls like getElementsByClassName. Also NodeList and HTMLCollection dont have methods like querySelector*, so calls like `getElementsByTagName().querySelectorAll()` is going to throw an error

Comment: If you've used jQuery in the past, you may be confusing that syntax experience with this standard JavaScript syntax. jQuery adds all sorts of features in its 9000 lines of code that ease the burden of coding tasks, but those concepts don't transfer outside of that library.

Comment: I'd be much easier if you can add an ID to the form. Many answers exist for that

Answer (score -1):

It's because `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` goes to children. Use `querySelectorAll('input[required]')`

Comment: as mentioned i already tried using querySelectorAll (x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input").querySelectorAll("[required]");), but do data is coming

Comment: Just take 10seconds to read what people wrote before complaining that it's not working.

`x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input")` returns you a `NodeList`, that don't have `querySelectorAll` method.

Plus, `querySelector*` search into children, not current Node. So as there is no [required] child for input, this will also not work, even if implements by browsers.

Comment: The first part returns a list of strings of the HTML attribute "name" of each field found in the form. Using `querySelectorAll('input[required]')` on this list returns "is not a function"